# How to truncate text of last item in horizontal ul list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an HTML list as follows...

```
<ul>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>Some more text</li>
    <li>Even more text</li>
</ul>
```

...and I'm using `display: inline-block;` to keep the list items on a single horizontal line.

The `ul`'s `width` is limited and I want to truncate the last item using an ellipsis when it doesn't fit into that `width`.

So needs to look something like:

`Some text   Some more text   Even mo...`

I've tried using `text-overflow: ellipsis;` on the `ul`, but to no effect.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some more text</li>
  <li>Even more text</li>
</ul>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x018wrf7/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got it to
work when setting `<li>` to `display: inline`.

The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-css3-text-20101005/#text-overflow0) for `text-overflow` states that it only applies to block elements. I guess having `display: inline-block` on `<li>` lets them have their own block context and thus the parent's `text-overflow` property isn't applied anymore.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 250px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some more text</li>
  <li>Even more text</li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/gmjc13za/)

Answer (score 7):

because you are appying it to `ul` instead you should apply to `li`, see below:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin-right: 10px;
  max-width: 110px
}
li:last-of-type {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some more text</li>
  <li>Some even more text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This clips all list elements, not only the last.

Comment: Thanks - yes I know that I could clip each individual item and that might be  the only way to solve it, but I was hoping to clip just the last one.

Comment: Thanks, that is a pretty good compromise.  I'll see if anyone has anything more complete, otherwise will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that Chrome is not behaving correctly, Firefox and IE add the ellipsis after the second `li` which appears to be correct behaviour:

> For the ellipsis and string values, implementations must hide characters and atomic inline-level elements at the applicable edge(s) of the line as necessary to fit the ellipsis/string. Place the ellipsis/string immediately adjacent to the applicable edge(s) of the remaining inline content. The first character or atomic inline-level element on a line must be clipped rather than ellipsed.

*Overflow Ellipsis: the ‘text-overflow’ property (http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-ui-20120117/#text-overflow0)*

`inline-block` elements are classed as atomic inline-level elements:

> Inline-level boxes that are not inline boxes (such as replaced inline-level elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements) are called atomic inline-level boxes because they participate in their inline formatting context as a single opaque box.

*Inline-level elements and inline boxes (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-boxes)*

Which according to the first quote suggests that the whole `li` should be replaced with the ellipses like Firefox and IE do.

To make this work consistently across a range of browsers change the `li` from `display: inline-block;` to `display: inline;`.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden
}
li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some more text</li>
  <li>Even more text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In Firefox his original code clips away the entire last list item, not only part of its text. I guess this is correct behavior and still a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @maryisdead That is true, although it does at least show the ellipsis. Looks like there is a difference in how the browsers choose to handle this particular instance.

Comment: Yep, true. Safari handles it like Chrome does. Then again, IE behaves like Firefox. Guess, that's not really well defined after all.

Comment: I was just about to say the same about IE. Think you could be right that this is somewhat due to the `inline-block` elements creating a new block context, it's just that the browsers handle it in a different way.

Comment: I suggest this as the accepted answer. More complete than mine and explains what exactly happens.

Comment: It's nice of you to suggest that @maryisdead. In fairness it was your comments that prompted me to dig a bit deeper into the possible reason behind this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks sire, this is of much help to me. Much obliged

Comment: It should be noted that if we have display: flex on ul, this solution doesn't work.